# Properly implement ListView's addFooterView

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I've been learning Android development from a course and we made a note taking app. I finished it and I want to add stuff and improve the app. I tried adding a footer to the ListView but I keep getting a NullPointerException:
`Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo`

Here is the code I have:

```
  public TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.footer_text); 
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.task_list);
        mTaskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(mTasks);
        listView.setAdapter(mTaskAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mLastPositionClicked = position;
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Task " + (position + 1) + " was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(TaskListActivity.this, TaskActivity.class);
                Task task = (Task) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                i.putExtra(TaskActivity.EXTRA, task);
                startActivityForResult(i, EDIT_TASK_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        listView.addFooterView(mTextView);
```

And the XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer_text"
        android:text="Works!!!"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Also, I apologize if the formatting is weird. This is new to me. Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/najubhai/dcff0ea72feea14673a8

Comment: On which line of code do you get this exception?

Comment: The first one, where I instantiate the TextView

Comment: Do you have a text view in the layout with the id footer_text ?

Comment: Yes, thats the one I showed the XML for.

Comment: @NajmSheikh there is no reason for that line to cause a NullPointerException. Could you please post your logcat?

Comment: Here's the logcat http://pastebin.com/g5xK7a57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call `findViewById()` before an Activity has a window, that method should be called in or after `onCreate(Bundle)`. Change your code as following will help:

```
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.task_list);
        // Move the addFooterView line to here, because this method 
        // could only be called before setting the adapter with setAdapter before  KITKAT(Android 4.4)
        listView.addFooterView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_footer_layout, null));
        mTaskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(mTasks);
        listView.setAdapter(mTaskAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mLastPositionClicked = position;
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Task " + (position + 1) + " was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(TaskListActivity.this, TaskActivity.class);
                Task task = (Task) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                i.putExtra(TaskActivity.EXTRA, task);
                startActivityForResult(i, EDIT_TASK_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now tho I had to change it up to this  
`listView.addFooterView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.footer, null),mTextView,false);`